# How to create Class based dynamic quota?

Tags: apigee

Please let me know how to create class based dynamic quota. In http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/rate-limit-api-traffic-using-quota url, I see a sentence like "*(To make this work, you would need to add a custom attribute called developer_segment to your access token profiles.)*"

Please let me know the steps to create "developer_segment" in access token profiles ? Is it to be created "OAuth" api proxies or the API proxy which is to be consumed.

Also share if you have any other way to create class based dynamic quota.

Thanks,
Damodaran

Answer (score 0):

"developer_segment" is the custom attribute set in the access-token, custom attribute has been set by configuring the attribute in the 'GenerateAccessTokenPolicy'. In the following link, http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/api/oauth-flow-variables, sample policy '' sets the attribute '1' as 'value1' and attribute '2' as value 2.
During verification of access tokens these attribute-values can be accessed as flow variables (accesstoken.).

Note:
  In ref="accesstoken.developer_segment",ref can point to any variable it need not be an attribute in accesstoken.